# licence of iOS simulator device background image

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

iOS Simulator comes with these nicely polished background images for various devices. If possible I'd like to use those for promotional purposes for my app. I couldn't find any informations about their license terms and whether Apple allows such usage (after all it's promotion for their Appstore too). Does anyone here have any info on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marketing images are available from

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/marketing/index.html

(Required sign in using your developer account)

This has images for all devices, as well as the App Store badges etc.

You can get screenshots without the simulator bezel by using the menu for the iOS simulator - that prevents you having to crop out to use the marketing images.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't seen these resources yet. I've downloaded the PSD's they provide. The light color is slightly different compared to the simulator background mask - a bit annoying to do all the cropping work just to get basically the same result. 

Btw. did you read the marketing guidelines? Some of that stuff strikes me as unintentionally humourous. "Do not use Apple product images on any disposable packaging or food industry promotions." "Do not overlap Apple products."

"One shall not ... " ;)

Comment: Yes, typical of this sort of thing I think. You can get screenshots without the bezel - see my edit. Reduces the amount of cropping work.